# User can't access chat in moodle?

Tags: moodle

I had installed moodle into my site.First i logged as administrator ,added chat.After that i logged as another user(student),I can show the chat icon ,but can not enter in to the chat room,shows the message "You are not allowed to enter the chat room".Any body give any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very common permissions problem in moodle, but it has an easy solution, for that do these steps hope will solve your problem

1- Login as admin

2- Click on the "chat" icon Then

3- In the left menu you will find an "ADMINISTRATION" block

4- Their you just need to click on " Locally assigned roles "

5- You will find the roles click on the student ,

6- Select the other account (student) click on "Add" button

Now logout from admin account and then login as student then enjoy Chatting ....
Hope it will work...
Let me know the status

Thanks & regards